# How to set devise in Rails to accept one specific email as a valid email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My issue in my RoR app is that the company email contains '-' like test@s-test.dk and when I try to create a user with the company email is saying is invalid.
I would like to know if the devises rules are possible to make a rule which will accept the company specific email but I will maintain the security.

Comment: You could override `Devise.email_regexp`

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice to validate emails is to use Regular Expressions. In your model - I assume it's 'User' - you should write something like:

user.rb:

```
...
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@s-test.dk/i
validates :email,
  presence: true,
  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
...
```

Comment: @Miguel Sampaio this do not help me seems I cannot put any email then

Comment: can you submit your inscription? Does the database get updated?

Comment: The DB is giving null because of the error and no update

Comment: Are you using a framework like `bootstrap` or `foundation`? What type of input field are you using in your view?

Comment: Bootstrap but seems the issue is with MX records and not with the regex.

Comment: If there is no insert into table it's not likely to be a mail problem. Can you transcribe your view and model?